# unique_ptr constructor with custom deleter is deleted

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unique-ptr

This example compiles and runs well with gcc 4.8.3:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto str = new const char[6]{'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
    std::unique_ptr<const char[], std::function<void(const char *)>> u_ptr(str, [](const char *s){ delete[] s; });
    std::cout << u_ptr.get() << std::endl;
}
```

But when I try it with Visual Studio Professional 2013 it doesn't compile (complains about a deleted function).
Is this not yet possible with Visual Studio 2013? Or is my sample code wrong and gcc ignores my mistake?

Error is:

> main.cpp(8) : error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr>(_Ptr2,_Dx2)' :
>   attempting to reference a deleted function
>           with
>           [
>               _Ptr2=const char * ,            _Dx2=main::
>           ]
>           C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\memory(16 16) : see declaration of 'std::unique_ptr>::unique_ptr'

Comment: There should be a FAQ on "why is using `std::function` as a `unique_ptr` deleter a terrible idea?"

Comment: [OT]: as you don't capture anything, you may omit unneeded `=` in `[=]`.

Comment: Shouldn't `T` be `char` instead of `char const[]`? This works on Visual C++ 2015 RC.

Comment: [OT]: You will have out of bound access to ouput in stream a c-string without nul terminator.

Comment: [`std::unique_ptr` already supports `delete[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) there is no reason to write your own here.

Comment: @T.C.: Can you elaborate or give some link about why is that a bad idea?

Comment: Provide a complete error message, please.  "complains about a deleted function" is unhelpful.  What function does the compiler say is deleted?

Comment: I don't mean to sound mean, but my go-to solution in situations like this is that your problem is trying to compile `C++11` programs with `VS 2013`

Comment: @rodrigo Exceptions. `unique_ptr` requires that all operations associated with its deleter must not throw; `std::function`'s constructors can throw, because it uses type erasure and may need to allocate memory under the hood. (In the OP's code it's even worse, because the `std::function` would be constructed before `unique_ptr`'s constructor is called, and if that throws then the pointer is leaked regardless of what `unique_ptr` requires.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be a defect in the Visual C++ 2013 standard library. I cannot reproduce the problem on 2015.

The `unique_ptr` class has this constructor for taking a pointer and a deleter:

```
unique_ptr(pointer _Ptr,
    typename _If<is_reference<_Dx>::value, _Dx,
        const typename remove_reference<_Dx>::type&>::type _Dt) _NOEXCEPT
    : _Mybase(_Ptr, _Dt)
    {   // construct with pointer and (maybe const) deleter&
    }
```

However, the `unique_ptr<T[]>` specialization also has a catch-all constructor:

```
template<class _Ptr2,
    class _Dx2>
    unique_ptr(_Ptr2, _Dx2) = delete;
```

This version is preferred over the previous one.

However, because the non-specialized `unique_ptr` doesn't have it at all, changing `u_ptr` to a `const char` instead of `const char[]` fixes the problem.

Using the array version with a deleter like you're doing is also unnecessary:

1. If you want to call `delete[]` on your pointer, there's already a specialization for arrays. You don't need a custom deleter.
2. If you want to do something else, you should use the non-specialized version.

Comment: as I mentioned in my comment on the question `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` is already provided. There is no need for a custom deleter here.

Comment: @Mgetz the OP is asking if his code is syntactically correct (And why the compilers disagree). The existence of an already suitable deleter is irrelevant, as he provided a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and he may need, in the actual real problem, to use a custom deleter.